# Get message "Cannot open display "default display", when SSH-ing

Tags: display, raspi-config, locale

Every time i ssh into my raspberry pi, i get message:

```
Cannot open display "default display"
```

I've tried going into raspi-config and installing all the locales. Doesn't change anything.
I've then tried googling it and nothing seems to work.

What do I do to make it go away?

Comment: Are you logging in using a console and trying to run GUI apps?

Comment: im logging in via terminal. no im not trying to run gui apps, not even -x with the ssh.

Comment: What app are you using to make the SSH connection?

Comment: no app. just terminal.

Comment: A terminal is an app. What terminal? Putty or WSL terminal can be used in Windows. What machine are you using? Windows or Linux or something else? Do you get the message after you log in? Does it stop you entering user name and password? Can you type any commands like `uname` or `ls -l -a`    ? Much more information please.

Comment: Im using an Ubuntu Linux terminal. I get the message upon entering. I log in via keygen so dont type in any password. Yeah I can type, it doesnt really stop me from doing anything and its just a nuisance and I dont know where its coming from and why.

Comment: Possibly there is something in the remote user's `.bashrc` file that tries to start something that wants to use the X display? That is what the message usually means. If you can't find anything, what happens if you edit the logged in user's `.bashrc` and make the last line to be `clear` and then log in again?

Comment: Temporarily rename `.bashrc` and see if the message goes away.

Comment: you're right. in the bashrc file i was sourcing multiple other files. and it turned out to be an xkeymap call that caused the message. Turns out the x in xkeymap is for... -x. I was so thinking this was some locale problem configurable in the raspi-config for raspbian has this locale setting problem i was always dealing with that caused errors akin to this one, so i was on the wrong track. Can just post an answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: see new answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common sign that there is something in the remote user's `.bashrc` file that tries to start something that wants to use the X display. That is what the message usually means. A lazy way around this is to edit the logged in user's `.bashrc` and make the last line to be the `clear` command. Advantage: hides the problem, disadvantage: you'll never know what is causing it. Best practice is to go through the .bashrc file and find if anything is being run that needs a running Xserver. Also maybe try looking in `/var/log/syslog` for clues.

Comment: Love the 'clear' solution. Problem still exists but you don't see it.

Answer (score 4):

> in the bashrc file i was sourcing multiple other files. and it turned
> out to be an xkeymap call that caused the message. Turns out the x in
> xkeymap is for... -x

You can test whether a console login is via SSH or not like this

`if [[ $(who -m) =~ \([-a-zA-Z0-9\.]+\)$ ]] ; then`
   `echo "SSH session"`
`else`
   `echo "not SSH session"`
`fi`

`who -m` produces hostname and user associated with stdin, and in an SSH shell there is output, and none in a GUI terminal, which we can test for. `who` plus **two** dummy arguments will produce the same effect, e.g. `who am i` (very popular), `who mom likes` or `who a b` etc.

The top grab is my Rpi4 GUI, the bottom is an SSH login from my Windows PC using wsltty.

[image]